# Remove sheared-off screws from a concrete slab?

Tags: concrete

An old door-threshold was fixed into concrete with screws.  Decades of wear and tear resulted in the shearing of these screws.  Is there a clever / simple / easy means of removing the screw remnant in the concrete and re-using the existing hole?

Update: I will need to chop the threshold because it is wide by one inch: this should enable at least one hole to align.

Comment: Chances are slim the new threshold has identical hole locations. Have you checked? Is there any of the screw protruding?

Comment: Unfortunately no screw protruding (great question).  If it were easy enough to remove the screw remnant, the worst case is to drill holes in the aluminum threshold?

Comment: I think isherwood is saying that unless the new threshold is the exact same make and model, the holes will almost certainly be in different places, so you'll need to drill in a different location anyway.

Comment: What about drilling the old screws out? The screws in my threshold are brass. They could probably be drilled out. Not sure about steel screws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tack weld a bar onto them and use that bar to unscrew them.

Or grind them flat and forget about them.

Comment: I had to grind down the screws flat and drill new screw holes in the cement.  Thanks for commenting